# Spark Streaming Example with Sockets

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, netcat

I'm trying to get the example spark streaming example to run but instead of getting input from the console created with `netcat`: `nc -lk 9999`, I want to send messages to this console and have spark listen. How can I do this.

So the idea is: Spark Listens from `nc -l 9999` (as example) and we want send a message from a socket. How can we do this? Is there a way of avoiding to have a server here and can we make do with `netcat`?

```
Other system -> Socket message -> nc -> spark
```